# cause parent process to stop waiting without exiting the process

Tags: c, linux

How can I tell my parent process to stop waiting without exiting?

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
  pid_t p1 = fork();
  if (p1) {
    printf("parent: %d\n", getpid());
    int stat;
    wait(&stat);
    printf("parent end\n");
  } else {
    printf("child: %d\n", getpid());
    printf("child parent: %d\n", getppid());
    sleep(3);
    //
    // I want to tell the parent to stop waiting here
    //
    sleep(3);
    printf("child end\n");
  }
}
```

Comment: Send a signal and hope the parent process handles `EINTR` errors correctly (few do)? So perhaps the child should start its *own* child process, and then exit normally (leaving its own child process orphaned)?

Comment: Also, what is your actual problem you're trying to solve? Why do you want to stop the parent from stop waiting?

Comment: @Haris this is a minimal code sample. I removed all error handling and added some quick prints

Comment: This seems to have some elements of an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to it.  What exact problem are you trying to solve?  What's wrong with the parent process waiting for the child to exist in whatever situation you're trying to address?  Whatever solution works might be highly dependent on the exact details.

Comment: @AndrewHenle My program forks and execs. Depending on some of the output from the exec, it may need to daemonize. My solution was to fork first (lets call these processes `p0` and `p1`), then the first child (`p1`) will fork (`p2`) and exec. `p1` will track `p2` (the exec), and if it should keep running in the background, it will tell its parent (`p0`) to stop waiting and exit.

Comment: Daemonizing usually involves the double-fork I mentioned in my first comment. Once the child process exits, the granchild process will be completely independent, and the original parent process doesn't need to wait for it.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Add a `setsid()` call in between the `fork()` calls to detach the deamonized process from the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up going with. It seems to work:

```
  pid_t p1 = fork();
  if (p1) {
    printf("parent: %d\n", getpid());
    sigset_t s;
    sigemptyset(&s);
    sigaddset(&s, SIGCHLD);
    sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &s, NULL);
    sigwaitinfo(&s, NULL);
    printf("parent end\n");
  } else {
    printf("child: %d\n", getpid());
    printf("child parent: %d\n", getppid());
    sleep(3);
    kill(getppid(), SIGCHLD);
    sleep(3);
    printf("child end\n");
  }
```

Comment: It's not clear why one doesn't need to wait sometimes for the child process to exit now so the parent can properly clean it before exiting, the parent process appears to have only one code path now like it could just exit anyway.

Comment: @Motomotes I don't understand your comment